# How do I create a node in cron job in drupal8?

Tags: cron, drupal-8

I need to create node once the cronjob runs in drupal 8.

I have trid this code. But not working.

```
function modulename_cron() { 
    $node = entity_create('node', array(
      'title' => 'New Article',
      'body' => 'Article body',
      'type' => 'article',
    )); 
    $node->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is also working...
But if you getting problem to create node then also try this code too.

You also use this code for node create in Drupal 8

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'New Article',
  'body'        => 'Article body',

]);
$node->save();
```

Comment: check your dblog, may be it shows some information about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use Drupal's entity.manager service:

```
// Get node storage.
$nodeStorage = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('node');

// Set node content.
$content = [
    'type' => 'article',
    'title' => 'title',
    'body' => [
        'value' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
        'format' => 'basic_html'
    ]
];

// Create a new node.
$node = $nodeStorage->create($content);

// Save the node.
$node->save();
```

https://github.com/BoldizArt/UsefulDrupal8Functions/blob/master/CreateNodeProgrammatically.php